# USB disconnect and new USB device using xhci_hcd

Tags: kernel, logs, usb

**/var/log/messages**

```
kernel: usb 3-7.3:USB disconnect, device number 69
kernel: usb 3-7.3:new low-speed USB device number 70 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 3-7.3:new USB device found, idVendor=0461, idProduct=4e22
kernel: usb 3-7.3:new USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
kernel: usb 3-7.3:Product: USB Optical Mouse

kernel: usb 3-7.3:USB disconnect, device number 67
kernel: usb 3-7.3:new low-speed USB device number 68 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 3-7.3:new USB device found, idVendor=0461, idProduct=4e22
kernel: usb 3-7.3:new USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
kernel: usb 3-7.3:Product: USB Optical Mouse

kernel: usb 3-7.3: Manufacturer: PixArt
kernel: input: PixArt USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14/usb3/3-7/3-7.3/3.7-3:1.0/input/input69
kernel: hid-generic 0003:0461:4E22:0043: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PixArt USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0.7.3/input0
mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 68: /sys/devices...{don't want to type out}
mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 68 was not an MTP device

.... repeats ~ every 1..2 minutes
```

Did not include the time stamps from the entries in the file, they did not go in sequential order.  This is with using a Dell optical usb mouse connected to server, which is running RHEL 7.6.

What causes this and is there a way to stop it?  It is especially annoying if at *runlevel 3* the monitor connected to server repeatedly displays this after the login prompt, as well as if anyone logs in at the terminal.

*I believe on another server also running rhel 7.6 I disabled xchi handoff in bios, and I don't think I am getting these repeated messages.  However on this server whether xhci is disabled or enabled I am still getting these entries in message log*

if you google images `M-UVDEL1` it is that mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed your **Dell MS111-P** Primax/PixArt mouse at upstream Linux kernel with **HID_QUIRK_ALWAYS_POLL** already. I even sent it to the linux stable mailing list. If your distribution did not pick up the patch, then please set the quirk by kernel boot parameter or report a bug to your distribution. TIA. With RHEL you should have support from Red Hat. They need to backport the patch to the old < v4.16 hid_blacklist or take the backport which has been done for Ubuntu already.

See: https://github.com/sriemer/fix-linux-mouse/issues/11

And: https://github.com/sriemer/fix-linux-mouse#usb-mouse-disconnectsreconnects-every-minute-on-linux